# PDF displays black colored background when loading in Docusign API iframe

Tags: docusignapi

when pdf loads in order to sign the pdf file through DocuSign API, it displays a black background with extremely large in the display. the file size is of approx 8MB. I then lower the resolution and tried to upload that file but the issue persists.

As per DocuSign API reply, the requirement for the resolution of the document is 100 - 200 dpi and the size of the recommended size of the document is 5 MB.

Agree on file size limitation but when I upload the same pdf(my associated 8MB pdf) direct to the DocuSign portal then it can be loaded and viewed properly without having the black background and in the proper display.

Please note that as I stated in my post, I reduced the pdf resolution and dpi. then file size was merely 800kb and then I tried with that pdf but still, DocuSign API gives an error.

So, can you elaborate to me on why it is erroring out with Docusign API and working properly on the DocuSign portal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question was also raised via DocuSign support and the problematic pdf file was supplied.

Results of my tests on the pdf file:

1. The pdf file is set to have a page size of 35.42 x 58.33 inches. I believe this is the real issue.
2. The behavior of the DocuSign system is the same whether the file is uploaded via the web tool or via the API. Therefore there is **no** API issue.
3. The pdf is shown successfully in the Sender (tagger) view, but not in the signing ceremony view.

Since the page size is not supposed to be 35 x 58 inches, the next step to solve the problem is to correctly generate a PDF with letter size pages.

Note that the resolution of a scanned image included within a PDF is independent of the page dimensions of the PDF.